# How to create a master/detail relationship with Telerik and OData?

Tags: entity-framework, telerik, wcf-data-services, odata

I have an OData WCF ADO.NET service created with Entity Framework using protocol version 2. The entity model looks like this:

[image: Entity model]

I now wish to consume this using a **Telerik RadGrid**. Here's the markup so far:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" Skin="Sitefinity">
    <ClientSettings>
        <DataBinding Location="http://aadev:8081/measuredata.svc">
            <DataService TableName="MeasureTopics"></DataService>
        </DataBinding>
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="MeasureTopicGuid" GroupLoadMode="Client" Name="MeasureTopics">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TopicName" />
        </Columns>
        <DetailTables>
            <telerik:GridTableView DataKeyNames="MeasureGuid" runat="server">
                <ParentTableRelation>
                    <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="TopicID" MasterKeyField="MeasureTopicGuid" />
                </ParentTableRelation>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MeasureKeyCode" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MeasureName" />
                </Columns>
            </telerik:GridTableView>
        </DetailTables>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

This shows measure topics and a right-arrow to expand into measure definitions, but clicking the arrow does nothing. At least part of the problem is that `ParentTableRelation` can't work as "TopicID" doesn't exist on the entity. (It's not there because having "MeasureTopic" as a navigation property prevents EF from allowing it to also exist on the entity as a scalar.)

What I'd like to know is, as the **relationship is coming through the OData feed** as a link...

```
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/MeasureTopic" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="MeasureTopic" href="MeasureDefinitions(guid'96df6072-a8e4-e011-890d-000c29ba97e5')/MeasureTopic" /> 
<category term="HealthMeasuresModel.MeasureDefinition" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
<content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
        <d:MeasureGuid m:type="Edm.Guid">96df6072-a8e4-e011-890d-000c29ba97e5</d:MeasureGuid> 
        <d:MeasureKeyCode>ABC-001</d:MeasureKeyCode> 
        <d:MeasureName>ABC Register</d:MeasureName> 
        <d:MeasureDescription>Test</d:MeasureDescription> 
    </m:properties>
</content>
```

...how do I **configure RadGrid to understand it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is mostly correct, only `GroupLoadMode` should be `HierarchyLoadMode` instead. The former specifies loading of groups, the latter - of hierarchical detail tables.

You also need some javascript, more specifically two RadGrid client events - `OnHierarchyExpanding` and `OnCommand`. The approach is demonstrated in [this Telerik Blog post](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/11-10-03/client-side-hierarchical-databinding-to-odata-with-radgrid-for-asp-net-ajax.aspx).